# seaborn stripplot ValueError: Could not interpret input 'OS'

Tags: python-3.6, seaborn

I am new to seaborn(version: '0.9.0').
I loaded my data from a CSV file in pandas but when I am trying to create the stripplot i get this error:

> ValueError: Could not interpret input 'OS'

```
import numpy as np
import matplotlib.pyplot as plt
import pandas as pd
import seaborn as sb
smartphones = pd.read_csv('D:\\Python Codes\\DataScience\\Smartphone.csv')
sb.stripplot(x='OS',y='Capacity',data=smartphones,size=10, jitter=True)
plt.show()
```

[CodeError](https://i.stack.imgur.com/1KhnO.png)

This is my CSV file:

[Dataset](https://i.stack.imgur.com/079KC.png)

This is the link to the CSV file:
[The CSV File](https://drive.google.com/file/d/1MZc79S7nhw60QoC1_8RpACZ9Im9WoxVL/view?usp=sharing)

Comment: I cannot reproduce this. Is that table available online? Which version of searborn are you using?

Comment: I am using seaborn version : '0.9.0' 
and this is the link to the file:
https://drive.google.com/file/d/1MZc79S7nhw60QoC1_8RpACZ9Im9WoxVL/view?usp=sharing

Answer (score 2, accepted):

For some reason some columns in the csv file have a blank space appended. This means that you need to access them with e.g. `"OS "` instead of `"OS"`. The following would hence work:

```
sb.stripplot(x='OS ',y='Capacity ',data=smartphones,size=10, jitter=True)
```

The more reliable way is of course to sanitize your input data prior to loading it. I.e. run a search/replace and replace `" ,"` by `","` in the file.

Comment: Thanks, that was the problem! I really appreciate your help.