# Seaborn 'Could not interpret input' error

Tags: python, seaborn, facet-grid

I have read posts with similar exception raised (ie:[here](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/51687122/seaborn-stripplot-valueerror-could-not-interpret-input-os), and [there](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/61713669/valueerror-could-not-interpret-input-rating)), but not particularly useful as the error was basically due to typos.

Below the very simple code that raises my error. Reading the seaborn doc and examples is not helping.

```
import pandas
import seaborn
df=pandas.DataFrame([[0,25.0,100],[0,24.0,95],[0,25.6,90],[0,20,120],[0,21,130],[0,22.5,115],[1,25.0,100],[1,26.0,150],[1,24.0,120],[1,20.0,200],[1,15.0,250]], columns=["meter","T°@T","meter-reading"])
df
```

output:

```
meter   T°@T    meter-reading
0   0   25.0    100
1   0   24.0    95
2   0   25.6    90
3   0   20.0    120
4   0   21.0    130
5   0   22.5    115
6   1   25.0    100
7   1   26.0    150
8   1   24.0    120
9   1   20.0    200
10  1   15.0    250
```

and then trying to plot FacetGrid:

```
g=seaborn.FacetGrid(data=df, col="meter").map(seaborn.relplot, x="T°@T",y="meter-reading")


Error: Could not interpret input 'T°@T'
```

the very odd thing is, .map encounters issues, but this other code works just fine:

```
seaborn.relplot(data=df,x="T°@T",y="meter-reading")
```

What am I doing wrong?

PS: the exception is raised in both Jupyter Notebook and Spyder

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I'm guessing it's an error because relplot itself can expand multiple graphs. So you can draw the graph by specifying `sns.scatterplot`. I don't think `meter' is color-coded because it's not a category variable.

```
import matplotlib.pyplot as plt
import seaborn as sns

g = sns.FacetGrid(data=df, col="meter")
g.map_dataframe(sns.scatterplot, x=df["T°@T"], y=df["meter-reading"], hue='meter') 
g.set_axis_labels('T°@T','meter-reading')
g.add_legend()
```

[image]

Comment: yes, while experimenting I also noticed that slicing the dataframe does the job. What I do not understand is why the example below works, and not mine.

"g.map(sns.scatterplot, "total_bill", "tip", alpha=.7)"

from: https://seaborn.pydata.org/tutorial/axis_grids.html

I mean, we are both using column names of dataframes after all.

Comment: I found out that seaborn.scatterplot and .lineplot do not encounter error with my initial code.
Therefore, another alternative is to use my initial code, like this:

`g=seaborn.FacetGrid(data=df, col="meter").map_dataframe(seaborn.lineplot, x="T°@T", y="meter-reading")`

Thank you, your answer made me try something else than .relplot